# Failed npm run dev with Tailwindcss

Tags: node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I just follow instruction from this youtube video https://youtu.be/lhCGoQkya5Q but i cant running npm run dev

---

in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Turtle\Desktop\My Site> npm run dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Turtle\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-22T19_13_01_984Z-debug-0.log
```

---

Project\css\tailwind.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a dev script in the scripts section of your package.json and from what I can see the tutorial doesn't explain what should go there. Try using "npx serve" instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new key in your `scripts` key

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tailwindcss -i ./css/tailwind.css  -o ./dist/style.css --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

`./css/tailwind.css` is your sour; change the name according.ly

`./dist/style.css` is your dist path/filename

`--watch` is to keep running and watch when you change something in your code